# How to outline and stroke this image in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, stroke, outline

I have this starting image:
[image]

I would like to achieve this effect, in terms of outline and stroke:
[image]

I want to cut it out an a Cricut machine. But when I go to image trace and outline I cannot get the stroke, no matter what size or color I choose, only fill works.

Answer (score 2):

1. Trace the image, choosing the *Ignore White* option in the settings
2. Expand the trace, Ungroup it, and do *Object > Compound Path > Make*
3. Copy it, and do *Edit > Paste in Back*, and change the fill colour to red. Note you won't see this colour change as it will be covered by the black object on top.
4. Do *Object > Path > Offset Path* and choose an offset to suit

[image]

5. In the layers panel delete the compound path in the middle

[image]

6. Select all
7. In the Pathfinder hit Minus Front

[image]

8. Round some of the corners at the bottom with the Corner Widgets, and you're done.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Other than tracing it with the pen too to make a shape I found an option that might work depending on how your circuit machine handles files.

1st: I took the image you provided into illustrator and image traced it to clean up the lines.

2nd: I moved the file to photoshop where I used the magic wand tool to remove the background.

3rd: I put a white color overlay on the shape which will not usually be printed or cut by most machines.

4th: Apply an outer stroke to desired thickness.

[image: Outlined Image]